# Pip refuses to install torch with GPU, disconnects from host when using -f [Work around found]

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, torch

I am running Windows 10, with python 3.7.9, with pip 21.3.1, and CUDA 10.1 installed. I've had pytorch installed on this machine before but am having to reinstall after some changes were made. I previously had no issues, but now when I try to install as before, torch can only be installed with cpu backing. I am trying to install
the full GPU version as I have in the past using Pip:

```
pip3 install torch==1.10.1 torchvision==0.10.2 torchaudio===0.10.1
```

However, this then results in me actually getting the version "torch==1.10.1+cpu", which is not what I need. I checked the site to see if there was any changes and found this version:

```
pip3 install torch==1.10.1+cu101 torchvision==0.11.2+cu101 torchaudio===0.10.1+cu101
```

However, this results in me getting a version error stating:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.10.1+cu101 (from versions: 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.10.1+cu101
```

Does anyone know what is happening and why pip won't allow this?

I've also tried using the url flag -f such as

```
pip install torch==1.10.1+cu101 torchvision==0.11.2+cu101 torchaudio===0.10.1+cu101-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html
```

and end up with an error:

```
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)", ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

**** Solution *****
If you follow this post and use a `--proxy` flag provided by the link in the post, it can work as a temporary solution. Another commenter mentions this is not a permanent fix and gives extra steps I have not yet tried, but plan to go back and attempt when I have time. Using the proxy flag, you'll need to try a handful until getting one that works, for me it was using the german flag `--proxy "5.9.89.187:808"`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Have you seen pytorch's [Getting Started](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) page? it will give you the pip command the recommend using.

Comment: Hi and thank you! Yes, I've referenced this page, and that's how I found the updated command including the -f. It seems like my issues seems to be resolving the interrupted connection while pip tries to install torch.
 I am able to install torchvision and torchaudio the same way, but it times out and disconnects whenever installing torch itself. Have you ever seen an issue like this?

Comment: If you open https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch/ and search for "1.10.1+cu", you'll find that there is only a cu102 version for pytorch 1.10.1